# SSIDs are not showing on network Manager in wlan0

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, kde

I am facing issue with my network manager. I am unable to view any ssid nearby. Every time i need to connect wi-fi by adding SSID and Password manually in network interface.

[Here is Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOiDj.jpg)

**Description Of Image:-**

> Opened Network Manager but can't view any connection even connected
> wifi too,
>
> networkctl,iwconfig
>
> /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections is empty

Answer (score 1):

Found solution. After restart it suddenly works.

```
sudo sed -i 's/^managed=false/managed=true/' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

then,

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

or

```
sudo service networking restart
```

[networking for some other Distros/Desktop]

If this does not work then try this command;

```
 sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

> Last Command Does not apply to every Computers.

### Thanks!

Comment: Please remember to accept your answer in two days time so others know this solution works.